# copy a file with applescript results in "Access Not Allowed"

Tags: applescript

I am trying to copy a file over another file using applescript.

```
tell application "Finder"
            copy file "Macintosh HD:Users:rkohr:Dropbox:Hacks:hosts.block" to "Macintosh HD:Users:rkohr:Dropbox:Hacks:hosts"
        end tell
```

Both files have be set with chmod 664, and should have permissions to be written to, but it gives a syntax error saying "Access Not Allowed"

Answer (score 0):

First, 'copy' —as a command— doesn't mean 'copy a file' in applescript. The command to copy a file with the Finder is 'duplicate'. Second, what goes between the quotes is just a text string until it is prefaced with 'file' or 'alias' or some such keyword. So your second reference (i.e. the destination) needs to incorporate that. As is, you're trying to have the script copy a file to a string. Finally, renaming the resulting file is a separate action.

Try this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    set sFil to file "rkohr:Dropbox:Hacks:hosts.block"
    
    set fNam to name of sFil
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ".block"
    set sNam to first text item of fNam
    
    set dFil to duplicate sFil to "rkohr:Dropbox:Hacks:" with exact copy
    set name of dFil to sNam
    
end tell
```

NB If you have a variety of file extensions, then you can get the 'name extension' of your source file and use that as the delimiter. The 'exact copy' parameter will include the file's permissions in the copy. There is also the option of replacing an already existing destination file. I'm assuming that your file path is functional but having it reach back to the disk (e.g. prepend with "MacintoshHD:Users:" or whatever your setup is) might be worth considering.